# How to query TFS-VersioncontrolServer for item-moves

Tags: c#, tfs

Lets say I have an Item-Id or ServerItem (path).
I need to know, where this Item has been moved

Current and old locations. 
How do I acchieve this with given Information on Serverside ?

Visual Studio can display all locations when you display the history of an item.

I tried versioncontrol.QueryHistory, however this only returns the history of the current itemid. Moving a file does change the itemid but i dont know how to get the different ids.

Querying merges doesnt seem to work either.

Lets say I query for **ItemId 1234**, i want the result to be something like this:

```
 - ItemId 1789 ServerItem $/somwhere/path1/hadTobeRenamedAsWell.cs  //newest

 - ItemId 1234 ServerItem $/somwhere/path2/item.cs

 - ItemId 1200 ServerItem $/somwhere/path3/item.cs

 - ItemId 1001 ServerItem $/somwhere/path4/item.cs // oldest
```

If this doesnt work serverside, does it on clientside?

This is the method i use to obtain the Items

```
private static TeamFoundationDataReader queryVersionControl(
                TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, 
                TeamFoundationVersionControlService versionConrol, 
                IEnumerable<string> items, 
                string workspaceName, 
                string workspaceOwnername)
{
    return versionConrol.QueryItems(requestContext,
                                    workspaceName,
                                    workspaceOwnername,
                                    items.Select(i => new ItemSpec(i, RecursionType.None)).ToArray(), 
                                    new LatestVersionSpec(),
                                    DeletedState.Any,
                                    ItemType.File,
                                    false,
                                    0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple method that should return the results you are looking for if you provide the current path to the file.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes out the history of changes to a file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path to a file similar to $/FabrikamFiber/Main/FabrikamFiber.CallCenter/FabrikamFiber.CallCenter.sln</param>
    private static void _GetHistory(string path)
    {
        using (TeamProjectPicker tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, false, new UICredentialsProvider()))
        {
            if (tpp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection = tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;
                VersionControlServer server = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
                Item item = server.GetItem(path);

                int changeId = item.DeletionId != 0 ? item.ChangesetId - 1 : item.ChangesetId;
                ChangesetVersionSpec versionCurrent = new ChangesetVersionSpec(changeId);
                ChangesetVersionSpec versionFrom = new ChangesetVersionSpec(1);

                IEnumerable changesets = server.QueryHistory(path, versionCurrent, 0, RecursionType.None, null, versionFrom, LatestVersionSpec.Latest, int.MaxValue, true, false);

                foreach(Changeset changeset in changesets)
                {
                    Item info = changeset.Changes[0].Item;
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ItemId {0} ServerItem {1}", info.ItemId, info.ServerItem));                        
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will take a look at it. This looks easier than expected.